# UNION ALL only returns the fist column

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to migrate some data from an old Access database to a new one, some columns changed, for example the old "adress" used to be divided into street, number, city and postal code is now only one column.
So I need to union all the columns into only one before update the new database.
I get no error and no warning, althought it only shows the first columns on the updated database.

What I'm trying to do:

```
   //Open the connection with the database
                    oldBuys.Open()
                    newBuys.Open()

                    Dim codTable As New DataTable
                    Dim codTemp As Integer
                    Dim addressTable As New DataTable
                    Dim tempValue As String

        //Command to find all the client codes on the new database
                Dim findAllCodes As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Cod FROM Data", newBuys)
                    findAllCodes .Fill(codTable)

    //Search for all the adress of that code
                    For i = 0 To codTable.Rows.Count - 1

                        codTemp = codTable.Rows(i).Item(0)

    //Union all the values
                        Dim findAllAdress As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Street FROM Data" & _
    " WHERE Cod=@cod1 UNION ALL SELECT Number FROM Data WHERE Cod=@cod2 UNION ALL SELECT City" & _
    " FROM Data WHERE Cod=@cod3 UNION ALL SELECT State FROM Data WHERE Cod=@cod4 UNION" & _
    " ALL SELECT postalCode FROM Data WHERE Cod=@cod5", cnCompraAntigo)
                        findAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod1", codTemp)
                        findAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod2", codTemp)
                        findAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod3", codTemp)
                        findAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod4", codTemp)
                        findAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod5", codTemp)


    //Transfer the value to the variable
                        tempValue = findAllAdress.ExecuteScalar

   //Try to update the new database
                            Dim updateAllAdress As New OleDb.OleDbCommand _ 
    ("UPDATE Data SET fullAdress=@end WHERE Cod=@cod", newBuys)
                            updateAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", tempValue)
                            updateAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", codTemp)
                            updateAllAdress.ExecuteNonQuery()

                        Next

                        newBuys.Close()
                        oldBuys.Close()
```

Comment: UNION is for combining rows from different queries, you look to be wanting to combine columns, in which case your query should concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished concatenating columns in a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT Street & ' ' & Number & ' ' & PostalCode & ' ' & City & ' ' & State 
FROM Data
WHERE Cod=@cod1
```

*This SELECT works under the assumption that all columns are alphanumeric, if some of they are numeric, you have to convert the columns before the concatenation.*

The UNION statement is used to merge the results of different queries, combining the resulting "tables" on one single result set.

For example, you can select all masculine names of a table and in another select statement retrieve all feminine names, using an UNION, you can combine both select statements in a single result.

**EDIT:** I've corrected the statement substituting + for & to adjust it to Access syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer were the most complete, so I choose your's as the right one.

Comment: Ended up like this:  

Dim findAllAdress As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Street & ' ' & Number & ' ' & City & ' ' & State & ' ' & postalCode FROM Data WHERE Cod=@cod", oldBuys)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need just this (`||` is the SQL string concatenation operator):

```
//Union all the values
                    Dim findAllAdress As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Street || Number || City || State || postalCode FROM Data" & _
" WHERE Cod=@cod1", cnCompraAntigo)
                    findAllAdress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod1", codTemp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a SQL Select like this:

```
SELECT [Street] & ' ' & [Number] & ' ' & [City] & ' ' & [State] & ' ' & [postalCode] 
FROM Data WHERE Cod = ...
```